# Install google play games without internet connection

Tags: downloading, google-play-games

I have a tablet that can't connect to the internet (I don't know why) and I want to install some games from google play. Is there a way to download them in another device and then transfer to the tablet?

Comment: Yes. See how to install APK files: https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=install+apk

Answer (score 2):

You can download a game and the use a similar [application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.usage.appbackup) to get the install file (APK) and then move it using a micro sd card but most of the games on google play store require internet connection to download some content . I don't see any utility of doing this